# Battery powered sconce for pictures

Tags: lighting

I have hung a couple of nice pictures around my house and I would like to hang a lighting sconce above them. Is a battery powered sconce a thing? I don't want ugly cables about. How do I light my pictures without the cables?

Comment: Did you Google it? https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=battery+powered+picture+light

Comment: There are thousands of battery power lights.  Just have to look for them.  This is only the first of many search hits,  just using this link because I did not want to look at others.   https://www.wayfair.com/lighting/sb1/battery-operated-picture-lights-c435200-a76613~280538.html

Comment: since this question as asked is closed, you could try rephrasing it in a new question, "How can I have sconces on my walls without visible wires, for permanent pictures?" and clarify how many, what the walls are made of, what your level of skill is...

Comment: i would get a motion activated light to preserve battery life.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with battery-powered lighting is *batteries*. Your mileage will vary, of course, but whether a light lasts a day (easy), a week (maybe) or a month (very unlikely), you will need to change batteries on a regular basis. That's fine if this is a temporary art exhibit - check all the batteries/lights each morning when you open. But in a permanent installation it really doesn't make sense.

The real solution is to run wires through the walls to provide power to lights. You have two somewhat different options:

- Traditional 120V (US) light fixtures

These have the advantage of very large selection of styles and sizes. If they have replaceable bulbs (instead of a permanent LED array) then you can easily experiment with different color temperatures and brightness. The big disadvantage is the wiring methods required.

- Low voltage (e.g., 12V) light fixtures

These use a power pack ("transformer", but often more to it than that). That provides the big advantage of more flexibility in wiring methods.

Any hidden wiring will require getting inside the walls. That often, but not always, involves cutting holes that need to be patched. A lot depends on your existing wall structure (drywall over studs vs. brick, etc.), location of the new fixtures, location of existing power, and skill of the installer.

Regular AC power (120V and up) has very strict rules as to wire/cable type and installation method. Generally speaking this means either thick cable (a.k.a. Romex brand name) or wires in conduit. Conduit is best installed with the walls open, but cable can often be installed with minimal damage to existing walls.

Low voltage (e.g., 12V or 24V) can use the same wiring methods as higher voltage, but can also, generally speaking, be wired in other ways. This is commonly used for telephone, network and alarm wiring, but low-voltage lighting can take advantage of the flexibility as well. However, you will need a power supply, which will attach to regular AC power and can't be hidden inside the wall.

Comment: LEDs can be fully adjustable for color and "white" color temperature, so there's a definite added bonus there. Also, I usually don't up vote answers on closed questions, but this is a good one. Glad you got it in before this was closed.

Comment: This is a blatant case of XY problem. The real question was not "What is a good battery-powered sconce?", which is 100% off-topic. The **real** question was "How can I have sconces on my walls without visible wires?".

Comment: If we flagged every XY problem and could get the OP to come back to clarify the situation...

Comment: In this case, it was pretty clear from the text what the real issue was. But I can't truly argue with the Close on the question as written, because it is clearly asking for a product recommendation. But that isn't what they *should* be asking. Argh!

Comment: You raise the right question: "How can I have sconces on my walls without visible wires?". But he did ask "How do I light my pictures without the cables?" which could mean without *visible* cables. But we don't know, and we would want "the OP to come back to clarify the situation" (Freeman)